# Multiple user ID matches in gpg

Tags: debian, git, gnupg

My GPG secret keyring contains multiple keys with the same email address. Although I can set the global default key easily enough (with `default-key`) some tools I use (for example, `git` and the Debian developer tools) always invokes gpg with `-u me@example.com`). This always appears to use the first key with a matching userid, and I can't find a way to influence its choice. Curiously the option `disable` in `edit-key` doesn't help.

The situation is that I have an old (1024 bit) key which I have deprecated, but I don't want to remove it from my keyring yet.

How can I persuade gpg to use the correct key when invoked with `-u me@example.com` so that these tools can work correctly? I can set `user.signingkey` option for `git` and the `-k` flag to `dpkg-buildpackage`, as a workaround, but that loses the useful ability to those tools to set an alternative identity.

Comment: A rather hacky-ish solution which I'm not totally sure it will work, thus not an answer (yet): Do a `--export-secret-keys` and --export` with your old key, drop it and reimport (make a backup of your `.gnupg` folder first). If GnuPG is choosing the first key found, this should be your new one now (and you're still keeping the old one).

Comment: This active issue in the gpg tracker is relevant: https://bugs.g10code.com/gnupg/issue1577. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to add a message to that issue! It would be good to clarify the issue (and that it can't be fixed by setting the default key) on that report, and also let the requestor know of the workaround.

Comment: Reposted as an answer as it apparently is. Feel free to accept it if nobody comes up with a better idea...

Answer (score 2):

A rather hacky-ish solution would be to reimport the old key to change their internal order:

Do a `--export-secret-keys` and `--export` with your old key, drop it and reimport (better make a backup of your .gnupg folder first). If GnuPG is choosing the first key found, this should be your new one now (and you're still keeping the old one).